# Configure a GCP Filestore on a GCP Windows Instance

Tags: google-cloud-filestore

I've been trying to mount the Google Filestore and use as a NFS Shared volume on two of my GCP Windows VM instances but I keep getting the error below. Any assistance is much appreciated. I need to figure this one out.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> mount 10.*.***.250:/logs_arcon D:\Storage

cmdlet New-PSDrive at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Root: D:\
mount : Cannot find a provider with the name 'D:\Storage'.
At line:1 char:1
+ mount 10.42.144.250:/logs_arcon D:\Storage
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\Storage:String) [New-PSDrive], ProviderNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of your command `mount 10.42.144.250:/logs_arcon D:\Storage` doesn't look to be aligned with the provided in the documentation examples.

The format shown in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/mounting-fileshares#mounting_a_file_share_on_a_vm_instance) should work:
`mount 10.0.0.2:/vol1 z:`

Comment: I tried the 1 showed in the docs it was still d same , find below the error message. Also cn some 1 tell m wht has 2 be entrd fr root  PS C:\Windows\system32> mount 10.42.144.250:/logs_arcon z:
cmdlet New-PSDrive at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Root:
mount : Cannot find a provider with the name 'z:'.
At line:1 char:1
+ mount 10.42.144.250:/logs_arcon z:
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (z::String) [New-PSDrive], ProviderNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ProviderNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand

Comment: But it looks like you have a `D` drive, not `z`. You need to specify your drive.